# Use-package for a mode

Tags: major-mode, use-package

it's not clear for me how should I set use-package to load a package when a mode is activated.

I have read different things about :mode, :init :config and I am now confused.
Could someone explains it to me ?

A good exemple to me would be to start yasnipped in prog-mode.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, it's just that I don't understand how to ask use-package to use yasnippet only for prog modes.

I have read the official page and other pages but due to my lack of good english I don't understand how manage this task.


So if someone would be kind enough to tell me how to do it I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below snippet does the following:

- It calls `yas-minor-mode` when `prog-mode-hook` is called.
- The `yasnippet` package gets loaded/required automatically when `yas-minor-mode` is called. *So if you do not open a buffer with a `prog-mode` derived major mode, then `yas-minor-mode` is not called, and so `yasnippet` is not loaded at all.*
- Once `yasnippet` is loaded, `yas-reload-all` is called.

Please see the comments in below snippet for explanation.

```el
(use-package yasnippet
  :commands (yas-minor-mode) ; autoload `yasnippet' when `yas-minor-mode' is called
                                        ; using any means: via a hook or by user
                                        ; Feel free to add more commands to this
                                        ; list to suit your needs.
  :init ; stuff to do before requiring the package
  (progn
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode))
  :config ; stuff to do after requiring the package
  (progn
    (yas-reload-all)))
```

For macros like `use-package`, the `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` command is very valuable; simply put the cursor after the ending parenthesis of the macro form and call that command. For the above snippet, you will see,

```el
(progn
  (unless
      (fboundp 'yas-minor-mode)
    (autoload #'yas-minor-mode "yasnippet" nil t))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (progn
        (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode))
    (error
     (ignore
      (display-warning 'use-package
                       (format "%s %s: %s" "yasnippet" ":init"
                               (error-message-string err))
                       :error))))
  (eval-after-load 'yasnippet
    '(progn
       (condition-case-unless-debug err
           (progn
             (yas-reload-all))
         (error
          (ignore
           (display-warning 'use-package
                            (format "%s %s: %s" "yasnippet" ":config"
                                    (error-message-string err))
                            :error))))
       t)))
```

Comment: What does it do ?

Comment: It does what you asked in the question :) I will update the answer for clarity.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto Let me know if the added explanation helps.

Comment: Actually I understood the first code, it's the second that I didn't understand, that's because I haven't tried [code]pp-macroexpand-last-sexp[/code] !

Ok so it's the code used by use-package...
I will try to understand properly what it does, I cound't have written it myself !

Thank you that was really helpful !

Comment: Just to be clear `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` command is available in emacs core. It is used to understand what any elisp macro is doing behind the scenes, not just for `use-package`. The second snippet above is actually what the `use-package` form in the first snippet expands to. Again, to clarify, I did not write the second snippet by myself. It was generated by `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` and pasted it here to help understand what the `use-package` form is actually doing. If you don't understand it 100% right now, it is OK. Over time, you can learn more elisp to cover stuff like `fboundp` etc.

Answer (score 10):

As the [README](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/README.md) will tell you, the `:mode` keyword allows you to define a *deferred binding* (i.e. on-demand), which will load the package when visiting a buffer which filename matches the expression you provided.

The `:init` and `:config` keywords are what you are looking for:
They allow you to respectively execute code **before** and **after** the package is loaded.

Keeping this in mind, here's what you could do to only load yasnippet in prog-mode buffers:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure t
  :init (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode)
  :config (yas-reload-all))
```

Using this snippet, yasnippet will actually be *loaded* on startup, but will only be *enabled* in the buffers which major mode derive from `prog-mode`. The appropriate snippets (if any) will then be loaded just-in-time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I wanted to enable it only for C-mode whis is equivalent to .c files or .h, I could do it with :mode, am I right ?

If yes and if I have truely understand, in that case it would be better to use :mode because it the package would be loaded only when needed, correct me if I'm wrong.

In my case it's not what I want, but it's for my comprehension.

Comment: As I understand it, `:mode` is not really the appropriate keyword here; It is rather used to load the major-mode provided by the package (say, tuareg-mode) when visiting buffers which match the provided expression (e.g. `"\\.ml\\'"` for ocaml files).

Comment: Are you saying that :mode is more appropriate for major mode requirement ?

Comment: I believe so. Yasnippet is meant to be used as a *minor* mode (that may be global), not as a *major* mode.

Comment: Also see [yasnippet's README about this](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet#use-yas-minor-mode-on-a-per-buffer-basis)